# lib functions wont compile

Tags: excel, vba

sorry for what feels like a lazy question but not finding what should be an easy Google answer.

the declarations below are from some code i found to make what looks like a nice [vba GUID](http://exceltitan.com/guid-vba/) but compiler gives a vague "undefined user type" error. Thought maybe changing LongPtr to LongLong but no good.

How can I get this to compile? Environmentt is Office 365 64 bit. Thanks!

```
'// Test for 32 or 64 bit Excel
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32.dll" (guid As GUID_TYPE) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function StringFromGUID2 Lib "ole32.dll" (guid As GUID_TYPE, ByVal lpStrGuid As LongPtr, ByVal cbMax As Long) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32.dll" (guid As GUID_TYPE) As Long
    Private Declare Function StringFromGUID2 Lib "ole32.dll" (guid As GUID_TYPE, ByVal lpStrGuid As LongPtr, ByVal cbMax As Long) As Long
#End If
```

Comment: Did you add the `GUID_TYPE` code? Lines 11-17 from the code in that link.

Comment: FYI `VBA7` doesn't care for the bitness of the host, only the version of Visual Basic for Applications (VBA6 doesn't have a `LongPtr` type or a `PtrSafe` modifier). `Win64` (despite its name) will be `True` if the host application is 64-bits (and thus supports `LongLong`; the bitness determines the size of `LongPtr`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the `GUID_TYPE` UDT is being highlighted. You need to define that structure, using a `Private Type`:

```
Private Type GUID_TYPE
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(7) As Byte
End Type
```

Also note, that `Test for 32 or 64 bit Excel` comment is very misleading - `VBA7` doesn't care for the bitness of the host, only the version of Visual Basic for Applications (VBA6 didn't have a `LongPtr` type or a `PtrSafe` modifier). The `Win64` precompiler constant (despite its name) will be `True` if the host application is 64-bit (and thus supports `LongLong`; the bitness determines the size of `LongPtr`).

Comment: Yes, I had the type but it was called "guid" in the copied code not "GUID_TYPE". And the compiler highlighted the declaration, so I didn't put it together. Thanks!